# Ruby on rails: ActionController::RoutingError in Posts#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In routes.rb =>

```
get "categories/listarchive"

resources :posts
resources :categories
```

In `categories_controller.rb` I have `def listarchive end;` and there is a view `listarchive.html.erb`

But I got this error:  ActionController::RoutingError in Posts#index

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have app/controllers/posts_controller.rb file and a method called "index" there. Did you use scaffolding or manually write the code?

Also, could you paste more of the error message? Maybe in index action you have a redirect with invalid url?

Comment: Showing app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #40 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"categories", :action=>"listarchive"}  in application.html.rb i have this:       <%= link_to t.category_name, :controller=>'categories', :action=>'listarchive' %><br/>

Comment: Sorry for late answer, could you paste relevant line(s) from config/routes.rb ?